# How does one write density as a form?

Tags: differential-geometry, density

In vector calculus, given the density $\rho$ of a body with volume $V$, it's total mass $M$ is simply $M=\int_V \rho dV$.

If density $\rho$ is a form, say *dm* it would need to be a volume form to integrate over volume $V$; so we have total mass $M=\int_V dm$; but then by Stokes theorem this is also $\int_{\partial V} m$; which means the symbol $m$ must represent a kind of surface density - but this can't be right; as there is no way in general to distribute all the mass of the body to the surface in a generic manner.

How then does one think about mass density in the technology of forms? Is density even the right concept here? Should it say be a current instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Density is a 3-form, since you would write it as
$$\omega:=\rho\text dx\wedge\text dy\wedge\text dz.$$
In special relativity it remains (the time component of) a 3-form. More specifically you have a *current* density $J$ of the form
$$J = \rho\text dx\wedge\text dy\wedge\text dz + J_x \text dt\wedge\text dy\wedge\text dz+ J_y \text dx\wedge\text dt\wedge\text dz + J_z\text dx\wedge\text dy\wedge\text dt.$$

Observe that in general $\omega$ need not be the exterior derivative of another form, so $\text dm$ is just a symbol to indicate a small amount of a scalar quantity, not the differential of something, which would then be a 2-form (and $m$ is, if anything, a 0-form).

Comment: Thanks.  So my use of Stokes theorem was void since the density form need not be exact.