# What is the Lie derivative of the field describing the change of mass?

Tags: differential-geometry, conservation-laws, differentiation, vector-fields

I'm trying to understand Ch. 3.2 of the paper [On Bubble Rings and Ink Chandeliers by Padilla et al.](https://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/wp_padilla/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/On_Bubble_Rings_and_Ink_Chandeliers.pdf). I'm trying to understand the derivation of equation (15). Right now I'm stuck at the point where its about to state the conservation law of volume.

I am currently at the step where I am trying to understand the equation describing the conservation of volume. The equation according to the paper is:

$$ \partial _t^E (V) + \mathcal L_v (V) = 0, $$

where $\mathcal L$ is the Lie derivative and $\partial_t ^E$ denotes the Eulerian partial derivative after time (and $V = \pi a^2ds$).

From what I understood, the field describing the volume is a scalar field. That is, $\mathcal L_v(V)$ is the derivative of a scalar field along a vector field. Is there a need for a "Lie" derivative there? In all I have read about Lie derivatives, it is always about the derivative of a vector field along another vector field. Wikipedia says "Although there are many concepts of taking a derivative in differential geometry, they all agree when the expression being differentiated is a function or scalar field. Thus in this case the word "Lie" is dropped, and one simply speaks of the derivative of a function. "(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative). So here it would simply be the derivative (without Lie) along the velocity vector field $v$? Is there a simpler term for this than $\mathcal L_v$?

And, the sum $\partial _t^E (V) + \mathcal L _v(V) $ is zero, since $ \mathcal L_v(V) = -\partial _t^E (V)$? Is that correct?

(I'm not that familiar with the Lie derivative.)

Comment: Form MathSE: "Reynolds transport theorem: link with the Lie derivative?" https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771037/532409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just that you have mathematical issue when you want to write a continuity equation, ie a conservation law. For a scalar function $f$, you'd write something like:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+v \cdot \nabla f = 0
$$
(in physics, think of temperature, velocity components etc.) However, if you are considering densities $\phi$, you'd rather write:
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}+\nabla  \cdot (\phi v) = 0
$$
(in physics, think of any density mass, charge density, momentum density etc.)

While in appearance, the formulas appear different, they are consistent. The additional $\phi\nabla\cdot v$ term in the second equation compensates for the change in volume due to the flow, which is relevant since $\phi$ is a density. In order to unify these two approaches, the Lie derivative is a handy formalism. Instead of taking the derivative of functions, you take the derivative of differential forms $\omega$. For scalar functions, it's a $0$ form: $\omega=f$, while for densities, it's $3$ forms $\omega=\phi d^3x$. In either case, the continuity equation is always written:

$$
\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial t} + \mathcal L_v \omega = 0
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I see the notation with the Lie derivative is convenient because there's no need to distinguish between forms; it's the same notation for all  "dimensions". Was I correct with my assumption that volume $\pi a^2 ds$ is a scalar field, so it's a 0 form? I don't really see why densities are 3 forms. Could you suggest any literature to read to understand this? I tried to understand this reading https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/DGPDEC/ and I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184172/how-does-one-write-density-as-a-form) explanation on Stackexchange.

Comment: no problem, exactly. I didn't have time to read the article, but it looks more like a $1$ form. Densities are $3$ forms because you need to add the volume element which is a three form. Check out Arnold's Mathematical Methods to Classical Mechanics. K. Crane's courses are an excellent starting point as well.